# Функция для замены всех имён в строке на их псевдонимы из таблицы?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть таблица псевдонимов:

```
Name    nickname
vikram  vik
James   Jim
Robert  Bob
Charles Dick
Richard Dick
Rich    Dick
```

Хочу создать функцию для замены имен на псевдонимы из таблицы выше. Так хочу вызывать:

```
func_nicknames('vikram, James, Rajesh, Robert')
```

и хочу получить такой результат: `'vik, Jim, Rajesh, Bob'`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_nicknames( in_val varchar2)
RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    O_VAL VARCHAR2(100) := in_val;
BEGIN
    SELECT REPLACE(O_VAL,t.name,t.nickname) INTO O_VAL 
    FROM nicknames t;
    RETURN(O_VAL);
END func_nicknames;
```

Когда вызываю, получаю ошибку:

```
select func_nicknames ('vikram, James, Rajesh, Robert') result from dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
```

Совсем всё не так делаю, или можно устранить эту ошибку?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Oracle function to replace all names to their nick names?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65510067) от участника [@Vikash Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10061734/vikash-kumar)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/65510067

Answer (score 2):

Сначала нужно преобразовать параметр в табличную форму, остальное понятно и просто:

```
create or replace function getNicknames (names varchar2) return varchar2 is
    ret varchar2 (32000);
begin
    with names (name) as (
        select trim (column_value)
        from xmlTable (('"'||replace (names, ',', '","')||'"')) x
    )
    select 
        listagg (coalesce (nickname, na.name), ', ') within group (order by null) into ret 
    from names na
    left join nicknames ni on ni.name=na.name;
    return ret;
end;
/
```

Запустить и получить результат:

```
exec dbms_output.put_line ('result='||getNicknames ('vikram, James, Rajesh, Robert'));    

result=vik, Jim, Rajesh, Bob
```

[На db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=140f6b38925d9c13c3925116209b6390).

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65514509) от участника [@0xdb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6571020/0xdb)</sub>